# Email markup for online events was rejected

Tags: google-schemas

We have both offline and online events so `eventAttendanceMode` was included in the email markup.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "EventReservation",
    "eventAttendanceMode": "https://schema.org/OfflineEventAttendanceMode",
    "reservationNumber": "xxxxxxx",
    "reservationStatus": "https://schema.org/ReservationConfirmed",
    "underName": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "xxxxx"
    }
    "modifyReservationUrl": "http://hasgeek.com/fifthelephant/2023-12/",
    "numSeats": "1",
    "reservationFor": {
      "@type": "Event",
      "location": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "address": {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "addressCountry": "IN",
          "addressLocality": "Bengaluru",
          "addressRegion": "Karnataka",
          "postalCode": "560071",
          "streetAddress": "7, 4th Main Rd,"
        },
        "name": "Bangalore International Centre (BIC)"
      },
      "name": "The Fifth Elephant 2023 Winter",
      "performer": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "image": "https://images.hasgeek.com/embed/file/c391fcfa5bf2436392afcd83672baaf1",
        "name": "The Fifth Elephant"
      },
      "startDate": "2023-12-08T03:30:00+00:00",
      "url": "http://hasgeek.com/fifthelephant/2023-12/"
    }
}
</script>
```

The template was rejected and this is response we received

**Missing required properties**
After checking the sample email with the Email Markup tester tool, we found that there is/are “x” missing required properties. Please check the sample email and fix it/them. After your fix please do not forget to send a new sample email for us to check.

*Additional notes: eventAttendanceMode*

Google's email markup tester tool doesn't recognise `eventAttendanceMode` property. Appreciate any pointers on how to fix this and get the email markup whitelisted.